# Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined in React + truffle DApp

Tags: reactjs, solidity, truffle, web3js, decentralized-applications

My Ganche-GUI and metamask is running. but I am getting following error
in console

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined
    at App.componentDidMount (App.js:17)**

Following is my code in App.js code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import getWeb3 from './utils/getweb3';
import CrowdFundingContract from './contracts/CrowdFunding.json';

class App extends Component {
state = {web3: null, accounts: null, contracts: null};

componentDidMount = async () => {
try{
  const web3 = await getWeb3();

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

  const deployedNetwork = CrowdFundingContract.networks[networkId];

  const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(CrowdFundingContract.abi, deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address);

  this.setState({web3, accounts, contract: instance}, this.runExample);
}
catch(error){
  alert('Failed to load web3, accounts and contract, check the console');
  console.error(error);
}
};

}
```

I have not put the render() and function returnExample here.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Did you connect to eth provider?

```
    const Web3 = require('web3')
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'))
```

Are you sure that you use web3 1.x.x? Because your code looks fine, if you use web3 v0.x.x, try this one:

```
    web3.version.getNetwork(function(err, res){
      let selectedNetwork = ""

      if (!err) {
          switch (res) {
            case "1":
              selectedNetwork = "Mainnet"
              break
            case "2":
              selectedNetwork = "Morden"
              break
            case "3":
              selectedNetwork = "Ropsten"
              break
            case "4":
              selectedNetwork = "Rinkeby"
              break
            default:
              selectedNetwork = "Unknown network = "+res
        }
        return selectedNetwork
      } else {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause turns out to be due to the fact that the wrong version of the web3 was installed unintentionally. I have used the usual npm command `npm install web3` but somehow wrong version (0.20.x) got installed. After installing the correct version `web3@1.2.1` problem got disappeared.